# Should a question about design using a specific technology go on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm making a modular game engine using OSGi. All functionality is provided by OSGi bundles.

This engine is using the Entity-Component-System pattern. Most things in the world are Entities. There are expected to be hundreds to thousands of them at any time. Entities are just Component containers.

My question is about whether using the OSGi *Declarative Services* and *Component Configurations* specifications to manage the Entity instances is a question more suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). It seems like more of a design question, but it's more about proper and intended usage of those two specifications.

[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) was excluded from this because, to my knowledge, there isn't an OSGi game engine framework yet, so I don't know if I could get an answer there.

Comment: @gnat based on that answer, this question would be better suited on Stack Overflow then, correct?